# What are the COVID entry requirements for going to Netherlands -> India -> Thailand?

Tags: covid-19, thailand

My journey is from the Netherlands to India to Thailand, I will stay a couple of weeks in India before going to Thailand, I'm going to Thailand on 7 Januari 2023.

Last year I got two vaccinations in the Netherlands, the last one I got was in June 2021. I didn't get vaccinated this year; do I need to do a PCR test to enter Thailand? And are there any other COVID entry requirements for Thailand?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.